# Image In Header Is Returning a 404

Tags: bug, status-completed

The header image is coming up as a 404:

http://sstatic.net/webmasters/img/SE-logo75.png

This comes from the following meta header on the page:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="http://sstatic.net/webmasters/img/SE-logo75.png">
```

I first noticed this issue when writing an article on how to implement the Facebook Open Graph Protocol:

http://coderjournal.com/2011/01/adding-your-application-to-the-graph/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will go out with our next build.  The correct location is:  http://sstatic.net/img/se-logo75.png